# Turn off monitor using command line

Tags: server, display, monitor, x11

I am runnning Ubuntu Server on my laptop. There is really no reason for the screen to be on. I have been trying to use this command to turn the screen off:

```
sleep 1 && xset dpms force off
```

The problem is I get the following error

```
unable to open display "".
```

Any idea what is going on / what is wrong? Any other suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: Do you have an X server installed? And it is running?

Comment: @enzotib I do believe it is installed. As for it running, I am not sure. How can I check?

Comment: Try running this first: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Comment: Non null output from `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg` to be installed. Non null output from `pgrep -fl X` to be running. By the way, if running you should be in a graphical session.

Comment: What I have is a command prompt. It is not in a gnome session or anything. I just want the whole monitor to turn off

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but doesn't the monitor have a power button?

Comment: @WarriorIng64: it is a laptop

Comment: Ah, sorry...missed that part.

Answer (score 83):

To turn off monitor in console, the command is the following:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

To regain control of the console on pressing **Enter** key, I suggest

```
sudo sh -c 'vbetool dpms off; read ans; vbetool dpms on'
```

Comment: You probably then want to alias this lot to something handy.

Comment: vbetool is available via `sudo apt-get install vbetool`

Comment: In my case this command really turned the display off and not the `xset` one

Comment: Strangely enough the command turns off 2 of 3 displays, the third remaining white for a while before having the machine reboot on its own if the command was executed over ssh.

Comment: @enzotib, I clicked accidentally to downvote, sorry. Please edit a bit the answer to I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @enzotib me too ;)

Comment: @enzotib how can i turn on monitor pressing any key but without your second command? is there any settings for that? after i turn off the monitor, i can't see what i type.

Comment: Doesn't work for me running Ubuntu Server 18.04. It appears to do nothing.

Comment: This seems to completely freeze NixOS

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: `vbetool dpms off` does not work and says `mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted` and then `Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).`.  Tried on X11 as root and via `ssh` as root and on text console as root.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.10 it doesn't work with the same error messages as the ones obtained by @Tino

Comment: I confirm that this command doesn't work on Ubuntu server 20.04 @Tino

Comment: doesn't work with 21.04 too

Comment: freeze on debian bullseye/sid

Comment: Can't turn it back on, and I can't see what went wrong.  `beep` command sounds OK.

Answer (score 60):

**Try these commands...**

To Turn Off:

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

To Turn On:

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force on
```

If your display turns off and then immediately back on then try the following which adds a delay of 1 second before turning the screen off.  This give a chance for all events to be processed by the X server before turning the display off.

```
sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

Comment: How do I know which screen is which

Comment: The following worked for me (also partially inspired by [@enzotib's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line#62861)): `xset -display $DISPLAY dpms force off; read temp; xset -display $DISPLAY dpms force on`

Comment: Be careful with this. I'm unable to turn my monitor back on with a test machine after issuing `force off`

Comment: Update: Pulling out and replugging all cables (including power) on the monitor has remedied the situation.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not work: `server does not have extension for dpms option`.  Blanking via keyboard shortcut (Fn+F6 in my case) works (a bit unreliable, releasing Fn often unblanks screen again).  But I need a solution which works via `ssh` when the Laptop's keyboard is out of reach.  (It's really annoying if you wake up in bed because the Laptop lights the room.  Just a short voice command could invoke `ssh` to stop the Laptop burning!  Note that I disable screensavers on consoles, as there is only one thing which is even more annoying than wrong time console blanking: CapsLock!)

Answer (score 53):

The `xset` command  mentioned in other answers will turn off all the monitors if you have multiple monitor setup. However if you want turn off only one or some of the monitor you should use `xrandr`.

First run `xrandr -q` command, which will list all the monitors and its current display settings. At the start of each monitor details you will find monitor name set by the system. You have to keep track of that.

I have two monitors (one is connected to DVI port and other to VGA port) and when I run the command I see this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 2726 x 2726
DFP1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1360x768       59.7*+
   ... (more details are shown here, but I have hidden it)

CRT1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1360x768       59.8*+   60.0  
   ... (more details are shown here, but I have hidden it)
```

In this output, DVI port connected monitor is labelled as `DFP1` and other one as `CRT1`. So if I want turn off the secondary monitor(i.e., `CRT1`) I have run this command:

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --off
```

if you want switch on that monitor again then you have run this command:

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --auto
```

Comment: I have 3 Monitors, 1 VGA, 1 DVI and 1 HDMI. When i ran: xrandr --output VGA1 --auto, it turned the VGA on, but it cloned the DVI monitor.

Comment: Hmm strange. Try --on instead of --auto

Comment: @HarshithJ.V. this is a good answer! Its better than the `xset` because xset turns on if you just press the touchpad etc. Btw hope you remember me from your previous company :-)

Comment: @Nishant Thanks for compliments. Strangely I don't remember you. Please ping me on any other social media as we can't chat over as its against the rules.

Comment: If you got crtc error, then type "chvt 7" before xrandr command, so that it reads "chvt 7 && xrandr -d :0 --output eDP1 --auto"

Comment: To save xrandr settings even after relogging, so that you won't get a blank screen,  you need to go to display settings in kde then set the **primary output** in size and orientation tab.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I would only add that (as in the case of @ThiagoPonte)  `xrandr --output DP-5 --auto --right-of CRT1` allows to turn back on the monitor without cloning (replace **--right-of** with whatever your setup is)

Comment: X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Answer (score 41):

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 (no GUI, X, nor anything graphical), and after breaking my back last night trying to turn off the screen I finally found the magic command:

```
setterm --blank 1
```

After executing the command the screen will turn off automatically every minute (if idle).

---

And even better, if you want the command to be executed automatically at boot, you can add it to the *GRUB commandline*, to do so we have to edit the next file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Once there, just add `consoleblank=60` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT`, it should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet consoleblank=60"
```

Then close the file and save it, after that just run `sudo update-grub` and *voila*, every time you boot the screen will turn off automatically every 60 sec. (again, if idle).

And this way (adding the *consoleblank* to the GRUB) works even from remote terminals (ssh).

Enjoy! (again)

Comment: Executing the above command I get: "setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank". What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying from a remote session?

Comment: @zx485 Check out the updated answer, now you can make the screen turn off from a remote session. I'm sure this will solve your problem

Comment: Just what I was looking for! This is usually included by default in most distros but not server-centric ones like proxmox. Works like a charm.

Comment: You can do this remotely via `setterm -term linux -blank < /dev/tty1`. The command `who` shows which tty's users are currently logged into. You can also "turn off the screen" so it doesn't react to keys via `setterm -blank force` and reverse it with `setterm -blank poke`.

Comment: Caution! The value passed to `setterm --blank` is minutes not seconds. I was scratching my head for a while until decided to read TFM.

Comment: Can confirm this worked well on Ubuntu 22.04 server with no X or GUI. Both the local and remote session solutions worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Blank screen after 1 min and turn it off after 2 min. Any keypress will turn it back on. Make it auto-start after reboot.

The magic command what will do all the work:

```
setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2
```

If you get error: setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank

- You are probably trying this command by SSH. You must run it from local of your machine, or do next stage of this guide.

---

### Make it auto-start

Insert command in executable file. Store it for example in hidden folder of your home directory /home/USER/.boot-scripts/screen-off.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2
```

And make script file executable by systemctl. Create file /etc/systemd/system/screen-off.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Blank screen after 1 min and turn it off after 2 min. Any keypress will turn it back on.
After=ssh.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=TERM=linux
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/console
ExecStart=/home/USER/.boot-scripts/screen-off.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Make it executable:

```
    sudo chmod +x /home/USER/.boot-scripts/screen-off.sh
    sudo chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/screen-off.service
```

And finally get it working and enabled on boot:

```
sudo systemctl start screen-off.service
sudo systemctl enable screen-off.service
```

To disable it:

```
sudo systemctl disable screen-off.service
```

Comment: Why does it need to start after ssh.service?

Comment: no effect on macbook pro

Comment: service works perfectly on Ubuntu Linux using systemd; thanks for the fantastic tutorial. This is great for a laptop server. Also @Drew this is "Ask Ubuntu" not "Ask Different" the instructions are for Linux not macOS.

Comment: I guess @Drew is running Ubuntu on his Macbook Pro... `setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2` doesn't seem to work on those machines.

Comment: Lacking support for `xset dpms`, running **`chvt 2 && setsid sh -c 'TERM=linux setterm --blank force <>/dev/tty2'`** as `root` via `ssh` does the trick at my side.  However **`chvt` likes to crash X11** such, that, immediately, screen and keyboard and, not immediately, network connections become unavailable.  I really have no good idea how Ubuntu 20.04 managed to archive this.  Probably NetworkManager hangs in X11, so everything goes south when DHCP expires or something similar toggles something on the network.  The machine definitively stays up, but is in it's own lonely Universe afterwards.

Comment: service files set executable will generate warning, request to set off.

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple monitors use this:

Turning off your second monitor:
(Assuming CRT-0 is your left monitor and CRT-1 is your right monitor)
`xrandr --output CRT-1 --off`
Turning on your second monitor:
`xrandr --output CRT-1 --right-of CRT-0 --auto`
This way xrandr knows not to duplicate the first screen.

Comment: I was testing this, turning off a screen this way is more like disabling it,  eg, the screen is still powered on. Its just not used. The `--off`'d screen cannot be turned back on with the screen's power button (because its still on / was never off).  It also messed with my desktop display settings, (from extended desktop to mirrored displays). If this was done to turn both displays off, I'm not sure it would be easy to turn them back on without logging in to TTY and clearing the monitors.xml file wherever it is. The more you know.

Answer (score 3):

@stiemannkj1's answer(inspired by @enzotib's answer) buried in the comments to @harshith-j-v's answer (works on my laptop connected to a monitor):

```
xset -display $DISPLAY dpms force off; read temp; xset -display $DISPLAY dpms force on
```

Maybe a mod or site developer can make a way to pull good comments out to a separate answer so that attributions and reputation scoring can be settled correctly

Comment: I added `sleep 1;` in the beginning, as otherwise the monitor would immediately turn back on.

Comment: The problem is maybe there isn't a function dpms -> ubuntu 21.04 hasn't

Answer (score 3):

You can set it with `setterm` remotely, just redirect your command to correct TTY on your laptop screen, usually is `/dev/tty1`.

Try this:

```
TERM=linux setterm --blank 1 >/dev/tty1 </dev/tty1
```

Comment: have to point out `<> /dev/tty1` is not same with `>/dev/tty1 </dev/tty1`. 
 the latter is valid in this situation

Comment: Your answer make it clear, thanks

Comment: Only solution on this page that works, Ubuntu 23.10 without X11. Doesn't even need root access.

Answer (score 2):

- Suggested way:

```bsh
xset -display $DISPLAY dpms force off
```

Move your mouse and your screen will come back

- Not suggested way:

```bsh
xrandr --output $(xrandr | grep ' connected' | cut -d' ' -f1) --off
```

Then you lose your screen until you restart your machine or replug your monitor wire :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. What I discovered is that on my laptop (an old acer aspire) the default screentoggle button is supported. This could be something like `fn+F6`.

This solution probably didn't work back in the day. I hope it'll help anyone that encounters this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Me Too, but I need something from commandline.  On my Acer `xset dpms force off` does not work.  **`chvt 2 && setsid sh -c 'TERM=linux setterm --blank force <>/dev/tty2'`**  (run as `root` via `ssh`) works, though, but often X11 crashes doing so, rendering screen+keyboard dead.  In that case, networkmanager seems to be unable to keep network connections alive, so the machine is neither dead nor alive afterwards.  All you can do is a long press of the power button.  Checkmate.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, but important！

### Notice `<>/dev/tty1`

I see something like `setterm ... <>/dev/tty1`
in this page more than 2 times.

have to point out that `CMD <>/dev/tty1`
　　is not same with `CMD >/dev/tty1 </dev/tty1`

The latter does the expected job in this situation.
// change `setterm -blank` value, and verify by `cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank`

NOTE: `<>FILE` not shorthand for `>FILE <FILE`
　　　// at least I'm sure in bash.

### Prove it

```
chen:/run/test$ cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
ls -lh /proc/$$/fd/
```

```sh
chen:/run/test$ ./test.sh <>./out1
total 0
lrwx------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:37 0 -> /run/test/out1
lrwx------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:37 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:37 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:37 255 -> /run/test/test.sh
```

```sh
chen:/run/test$ ./test.sh >./out2 <./out2
chen:/run/test$ cat ./out2
total 0
lr-x------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:38 0 -> /run/test/out2
l-wx------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:38 1 -> /run/test/out2
lrwx------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:38 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 chen chen 64 6月   9 13:38 255 -> /run/test/test.sh
```

### man bash

```
[n]<>word
```

causes the file whose name is the expansion of word
　to be opened for  both  reading  and writing  on  file  descriptor  n,
or on file descriptor 0 if n is not specified.

If the file does not exist, it is created.