# How to turn off/on the laptop screen using a command-line or shell-scipt?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, screen, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off monitor using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)

In my laptop i have a button to turn off screen, but it didn't work so i think if i bind it's function and add a command-line to it as if i press it the screen will be turned off and if i press it again it will be turned on.so how to do it, and what it the command line to turn off/on the screen(monitor) ?