# How to let gnome-screensaver turn off the monitor when locked in commandline?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, screensaver

I am using Trusty but not unity desktop. I lock my screen by `gnome-screensaver-command -l`. Seems like in default configuration, gnome-screensaver won't save my power. I found [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/preferences-advanced.html.en) which did not work.

What should I do?

---

When trying gsettings, I got:

> $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60
>   The key is not writable

And for the vbetool issue, xset could be used instead without sudo. But I still want something persistent, instead execute everytime I start desktop, or even everytime I lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I had same issue in 18.04. No matter what command I ran with gsettings I got  The key is not writable error message. Tried setting files to writable in /.config/dconf as suggested in other thread but it didn't help. 
somehow my user file in /etc/dconf/profile got misplaced. 
what I did was

```
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/profile
```

and edit /etc/dconf/profile/user, then add:

```
user-db:user
```

then

```
sudo dconf update
```

source: [dconf Settings](http://www.mattfischer.com/blog/archives/431)

hope this helps someone save some time figuring this out

Comment: Thanks. I am not using gnome-screensaver right now. So cannot verify.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround way is as following. Run both these command:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1
```

This `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1` command sets your screen time if it's inactive(1 second) but you need to create a Custom Shortcut and one shortcut key for that with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60`(inactive for 1 minute) value to disable that feature because it turns off your screen if you have inactive for 1 second ;)

[image]

Useful link:

[Turn off monitor using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)

 Also if you used this solution, you can define a shortcut key for that to turning on again. But `sudo` needs to enter password then you can remove password for that command **HOW To**?

You can configure your system that `sudo someCommand` does not require a password(in our case for `sudo`).
To do that, run `sudo visudo` and add the following line at the END in the file that opens:

```bsh
Your_USERNAME  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/vbetool
```

Then exit the editor and save it (CTRL+x).

Now you can use `gnome-screensaver-command -l &&  sudo vbetool dpms off` command from the command line or in your script without password. And define a shortcut key like `sudo vbetool dpms on` to turning on it.

Comment: @Magicloud Run updates `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and reboot ;)

Comment: not working. :-(

Comment: @Magicloud What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I am using qtile. But everything of unity is kept.