# How to turn off display on 18.04 server no gui

Tags: display, cron

I would like to have the display turn off while not logged into the system.
I can't find an easy way to do this.
I am new to Linux, and I tried this command

```
setterm --blank 5
```

and added it to `crontab`, but it does not work.

Comment: `vbetool` maybe? [Turn off monitor using command line
Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/a/62861/178692)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found a workaround

Open /etc/default/grub in your favorite editor; you will need to use sudo (for vi, nano, etc.) or gksudo (for gedit, etc.).

Then add consoleblank=0 to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=, parameter.

e.g. yours may say:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=0" Then run sudo update-grub, and reboot.

Comment: What about if you want to turn it on again?