# turn off screen from text mode

Tags: command-line

After an upgrade attempt, from 18.10 to 19.04, I found myself unable to log into Ubuntu GUI.

While it's an interesting story in itself, this forced me to consider Ubuntu Console (Ctrl+Alt+F3) as my main interface. There, I can log in and use the console normally, which is not so bad as most of my work and needs are on console.

With `tmux`, it actually works quite well, except for one detail : the screen never goes off.

Using `tmux` time out feature coupled with `vlock`, I can make the screen go blank (with a blinking cursor), which is the best I could achieve so far. But that's not the same as having the screen completely off.

Is there a way to turn off the screen from command line, and without being in a graphical mode like Gnome ? I could launch such command from `tmux`. Most of the solutions I found imply that the console is running from a graphical mode, which is not the situation I'm currently in.

Comment: On my machine, the current monitor brightness can be get by reading `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and set with e.g. `echo 100 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, does that or something similar work for you as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use:

```
sudo sh -c 'vbetool dpms off; read ans; vbetool dpms on'
```

Or other versions that I found in my Source: [Turn off monitor using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)

From a personal point, I would suggest you reinstall Ubuntu...

Comment: That could have worked. `vbetool` seems like it could be the right tool for the job. Unfortunately, in my case, `sudo vbetool dpms X` produces simply no effect on my system ...