# T100HA turn off display

Tags: 18.04

I have "ASUS Transformer Book T100HA".
I installed on it "ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso".
I will use it as a test server.

Question:
How to turn off display?

All these things:
[Turn off monitor using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)
did not help me.