# Real mode call failed on MacBook Pro when trying to turn screen off Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mac, headless

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on an early 2011 MacBook Pro 8,1 and I want to close the lid and turn the screen off.
I have succesfully prevented it from sleeping when closing the lid as described here https://askubuntu.com/a/594417
and from another answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1117586 in the same question, I created a script to trigger the screen on/off. This script gets executed I have confirmed that with logging the calls to it.

The first problem is (was) that

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

resulted in this

```
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).
```

So I tried the solution here
[Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop - is there any way toturn off the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277533/ubuntu-20-04-on-a-laptop-is-there-any-way-toturn-off-the-screen/1350374#1350374)
that adds this

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
sudo vbetool dpms off
sudo mount -o remount,noexec /dev
```

but it results in

```
Real mode call failed
```

and yes the screen does not turn off

I tried xset and xrandr but they can't open the display

The installation is headless without GUI

```
uname -a
Linux oldlaptop 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro
```

Any ideas how to turn off the screen, either using vbetool or any other?

Comment: The screen should turn itself off if nobody is logged into the console. If you leave the screen at the login prompt, does it not go dark after 5 minutes? 

Comment: No the screen does not turn off automatically, neither when lid is open nor closed

Comment: I have ended up at the same dead-end here!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact wall.

The only solution I found is turning off the screen after a period of inactivity. (This completely removes the need for acpid and lid.sh)

There are two options.
The first is to use the following command:

```
setterm --powerdown 1
```

Note: If you are testing this out, it doesn't work over SSH. So to test it, you need to run it from the laptop directly.
You can put that in a script and have it run at boot.

Second option, and what I did:
Add `consoleblank=60` to the GRUB commandline:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit line to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet consoleblank=60"
```

Reboot.