# Disable Laptop Display (xset and vbetool have both failed)

Tags: 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server on a Dell Latitude E7240 Laptop. I'd like to have the display turned off while closing lid and when i want to. I've tried using `xset dpms force off` which returned: `xset: unable to open display ""`

I've also tried `vbetool dpms off` which returned `Real mode call failed`

How can I achieved that?

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384221/real-mode-call-failed-on-macbook-pro-when-trying-to-turn-screen-off-ubuntu-serve) is a similar question. Does it help?