# Turn Monitor On/Off via SSH

Tags: ssh, monitor, raspberrypi, wayland, 21.04

i have a PIR on another raspberry pi. This one should turn the monitor on this ubuntu via SSH on and off.

My System: Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 2104

I read about this and found many answers about using xset ( xset -display:0.0 dpms force off ), but the xset doesnt work ( Server does not have the DPMS Extension ). I tried to use the ubuntu screen off and use of xdotool to move the mouse to enable the monitor - xdotool also is not working.
Now i found that ubuntu now use wayland and x tools are not working. For turning monitor on/off, i found that the new tool could be wlr-randr, but i get: compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1. With mousemove i used wtype, but get the same error message.

What could I do to turn monitor on/off in ubuntu 2104 with xwayland via SSH?

Regards
David

Comment: Have you tried the `xrandr` method suggested at https://askubuntu.com/a/154052/526300 ?

Comment: yes i tried this also, the error of xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --off is:

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  22

so i found the alternativ wlr-randr, which is not working

Comment: Did you try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/618554/140671 ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes i tried wlr-randr and get: compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1, with swaymsg i get: 00:00:00.077 [swaymsg/main.c:417] Unable to retrieve socket path