# How to make the external display as the primary screen while using the ubuntu live IS from USB drive?

Tags: boot, command-line, gnome, multiple-monitors, display

**The story**: My laptop screen is broken, only showing white screen, accidently the laptop fall down from the table while changing the OS from windows to ubuntu, by deleting all the files in windows

**Current Status**: I do not know ubuntu is installed successfully or not.

**My Plan**: Last week, I get to know that ubuntu 22 is released, so, I created a live usb to install the ubuntu 22 in my laptop by connecting the second monitor, and use the second monitor until I change the screen in the service center.

**Challenge**: When the Boot Menu shown, I selected the USB. At first, the ubuntu asks whether to install or try ubuntu without installing ubuntu. In that step, I cant able to see the screen in the second monitor, instead I am only seeing the ubuntu default display wallpaper, there I couldnt do anything. Then, I get to know that the display is extended to the second monitor instead of duplicating the primary screen[which is the laptop screen].

**Question**: How to make the second screen as the primary screen while using the ubuntu live os from USB drive[pendrive]?

**Thoughts**: Create Persistent Live Ubuntu os, and modified the settings to use the second screen as primary or duplicating the default screen to the second screen/second monitor, and
then install that os to the laptop with the modified display settings - is it possible?

**To note**: I used to connect different monitors with both HDMI and VGA, same issue is faced, the display is extended instead of duplicating the primary screen

Any help would be rewarded with Pokemon stickers, thanks

Comment: Sometimes the Bios has a setting to select the primary display. But changing Bios settings without seeing it might be a challenge.

Comment: The Ubuntu consoles are usually mirrored over all screens. Use "ctrl-alt-f2" (or maybe f3) to change to console. But it is difficult to change the X settings of the other session from the console.

Comment: Maybe this helps you on the console: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line

Comment: @Marco, Bios Setting is visible, Is it possible to change in Bios setting

Comment: Does your laptop not have a key to cycle through all the screen options? Most do.