# How to turn off laptop monitor using command line in Wayland?

Tags: command-line, display, wayland, plasma, 23.04

I am using Kubuntu 23.04 with Wayland.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/62858/124466) answer, which works in two other computers running (Kubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu MATE 22.04) X.Org, but this does not seem to work in my Wayland computer.

```
$ echo "$DISPLAY"
:1
```

```
$xset -display :1 dpms force off

server does not have extension for dpms option
xset:  unknown option force
```

How to turn display on and off using the command line, when the display manager is Wayland?

Comment: i would do `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`.

Comment: @Rishon_JR (Have you tried using that command? :) ) I want to just turn off the display of my laptop, and not log out of everything. Also Kubuntu does not use lightdm.

Comment: Okay, just a small confusion . You can do `sudo systemctl restart sddm`. Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line) if you want your computer to go to sleep.

Comment: I want the display to turn off while the laptop continues working. Restarting sddm will close all the running programs and log me out of the session.

Comment: maybe with package `swayidle` ?

Comment: Not an answer, but, might save your time ... Your display is obviously not `:0.0` ... You can check with `echo "$DISPLAY"`.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks - The display turned out to be `:1`. Now there is a new error. I have edited the question.

Comment: Wayland doesn't seem to be able to handle external power management requests/commands ... If `xset` is ever going to work for you on Wayland, it would be without the power management option ... So, try just `xset s off`

Comment: I apologize for the mistake ... I meant `xset s on`  or `xset s blank` ... it's the screen saver mode ... should be blank screen by default ...  Then, activate it with  `sleep 2 && xset s activate` ... The `sleep` call is necessary before the command.

Comment: @Raffa `xset s blank && sleep 2 && xset s activate` seems to do nothing.

Comment: Then, I guess you’d need to rely on the power management of the  KDE desktop like noted by @meuh below  … I don’t use KDE but AFAIK Wayland power management commands don’t work as expected due to the way it is designed/restricted as opposed to the full native power management capabilities of Xorg or at least not as accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use kde but I noted this
[page](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_Connect/Tutorials/Useful_commands)
talking about "kde connect" (which seems to be a way to type commands to a
kde desktop from a phone). It suggests:

> Turn off screen:
>
> `sleep 0.1 && qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/org_kde_powerdevil invokeShortcut "Turn Off Screen"`

I had also noted from somewhere, the probable equivalent:

```bash
dbus-send --session --dest=org.kde.kglobalaccel \
  /component/org_kde_powerdevil \
  org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut string:'Turn Off Screen'
```

If kde shares some protocol with wlroots-based compositors, you can try
`wlr-randr`.

Comment: +1 It does turn off the monitor. Is there any command to turn it on? Replacing the same command with `Turn On Screen` did not work. Pressing anything on the keyboard/mouse turns on the monitor, but when they are detached in my touch screen tablet, I cannot find any way to find the display on after this.

Comment: If there is no "turn on screen" you should probably accept this question and start a new question for that, as it probably needs a completely different mechanism.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi That commands apparently uses shortcuts defined in `systemsettings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> Power Management` If a shortcut isn’t there then you need to define/add it first if possible before you can use it … See https://phabricator.kde.org/D22261